# mapping function doesn't show any results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here i want to show the list of messages ,but the map seems doesn't work i'm getting the data through over the `console.log`

please help me where i'm wrong thanks in advance
[image]

```
const [messages, setMessages] =  React.useState([]);

const  handleSendMessage = () =>{
var mesg = document.getElementById('message').value;
socket.emit('send_message', mesg)
  let newState = ([...messages,mesg]);
  setMessages(newState);
}

useEffect(() => {
console.log("messages...", messages)
}, [messages]);


  { messages.map((data,key)=>{                
     <li className="mar-btm">
        {data}
     </li>
   })}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to `return` results.

```
  { messages.map((data,key)=>{                
     return (<li className="mar-btm">
        {data}
     </li>) 
   })}
```